# Change element attribute when window resized (using WordPress)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am very new to this and might be a newbie question with a so simple solution, but it is giving me a lot of headache.

I am making a WordPress site. Need to change a header image depending on a window width. Tried so many combinations that I found online, but none of them works. No idea if I should be using JS or Jquery.

This is what I got:

In my "header.php" file i have this:

```
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); echo " - "; bloginfo('description');?>" id="logo" />
```

In my "functions.php" file i have this:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'osmpg-logo', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/logo.js', array(), '20150329', true );
```

This is the problem. This is my "logo.php" file:

```
$(document).ready(function($){

    $(window).resize(function() {
        var logo = $('logo');
        logo.attr('src') += '/images/logo.png';
        var windowsize = $(document).width();
        if ((windowsize) <= 800){
            logo.attr('src') = str.replace("logo", "logo1");
        }
    }

});
```

I know that the script does execute. I see it when I use debugging tools in browser. It just has no effect on my image. It is always only the result of "get_template_directory_uri();"

What I want is to add '/images/logo.png' for 800+ width, or '/images/logo1.png' for 799+ width, after the result of get_template_directory_uri(); template tag.

EDIT:
Now I have this 'error free' code. Now I need to make it do what I need to do.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    // cache the element outside rezise handler, so that the DOM isn't searched on every resize:
    var $logo = $('#logo');

    $(window).resize(function() {
        //declare current value of the src attribute:
        var $src = $logo.attr('src');
        //declare current window size:
        var windowsize = $(document).width();
        //check current window size and src attribute:
        if ((windowsize) >= 800 && $src !== '/images/logo.png'){
            //set new src value:
            $logo.attr($src, '/images/logo.png');
        //check current window size and src attribute again:
        }else if((windowsize) < 800 && src !== '/images/logo1.png'){
            //set new src value:
            $logo.attr($src, '/images/logo1.png');
        }
    });

    // update logo when page is displayed:
    $(window).trigger('resize');

});
```

EDIT 2:
This code works, but only in IE. In Chrome, breaking point is 818px and not 801px. Any ideas? Maybe document.width includes browser scrollbar?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    var logo = $('#logo');

    $(window).resize(function() {

        var src = logo.attr('src');

        var logo_prefix = src.replace('/images/logo.png', '');
        logo_prefix = logo_prefix.replace('/images/logo1.png', '');

        var logo0 = logo_prefix + '/images/logo.png';
        var logo1 = logo_prefix + '/images/logo1.png';

        var windowsize = $(document).width();

        if ((windowsize) > 800 && src !== logo0){

            logo.attr('src', logo0);

        }else if((windowsize) <= 800 && src !== logo1){

            logo.attr('src', logo1);
        }
    });

    $(window).trigger('resize');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

First : `$('logo')` is not a proper selector. Selecting an element with specific `id` attribute, you should use `#` (hash) in front : `$('#logo')`

Next, [jQuery `.attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) does accept two arguments:

- **1** attribute name;
- **2** attribute value;

With `logo.attr('src')` you can read the value of `src` attribute.
To set the attribute, you have to pass the new value in second argument:

```
logo.attr('src', 'new_logo.png')`
```

Also, you should always check both conditions (window size and current logo) so that the logo isn't updated unnecessary if current window size and logo still meets conditions.

```
// cache the element outside rezise handler, so that the DOM isn't searched on every resize:
var logo = $('#logo');

$(window).resize(function() {
    //declare current value of the src attribute:
    var src = logo.attr('src');
    //declare current window size:
    var windowsize = $(document).width();
    //check current window size and src attribute:
    if ((windowsize) >= 800 && src !== '/images/logo.png'){
        //set new src value:
        logo.attr('src', '/images/logo.png');
    //check current window size and src attribute again:
    }else if((windowsize) < 800 && src !== '/images/logo1.png'){
        //set new src value:
        logo.attr('src', '/images/logo1.png');
    }
});

// update logo when page is displayed:
$(window).trigger('resize');
```

Comment: Thank you for a quick reply. I tried it and it doesn't work.
You did clarify some things for me.
-You are right about declaring logo outside of resize
-I understand now how attr works
-I understand that checking for src avoids redrawing the same thing
I will have to make some adjustments, because  scr will have a prefix (the path to wordpress theme). At the moment: "localhost/xxx/wp-content/themes/yyy"
-I knew I had to hook my function to something, and I lacked the 
"$(window).trigger('resize');"

But, this is what I get now in a browser:
[link]http://s24.postimg.org/g2hzoz2f9/111.png[/link]

Answer (score 0):

See https://api.jquery.com/attr/

Here is wrong expressions `logo.attr('src') = str.replace("logo", "logo1");` and `logo.attr('src') += '/images/logo.png';`. This expressions do nothing, method "attr" with one argument is simple attribute getter.

For setting attribute you must use two arguments, attribute name and value. In your example it some sort of `logo.attr('src', "logo1");` and `logo.attr('src', '/images/logo.png')`

And `$('logo');` selector return some list of `<logo ...` tags, you may need an image `'img'` tag or some element with id?

Comment: @Artur Filipiak was kind enough to point to all mistakes I made. But I think I have a bigger problem and that is the validity of my function calls. Maybe something with Wordpress. Maybe I need to use a JQuery dependency when enqueueing my script...

Answer (score 0):

Final code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    var logo = $('#logo');

    $(window).resize(function() {

        var src = logo.attr('src');

        var logo_prefix = src.replace('/images/logo.png', '');
        logo_prefix = logo_prefix.replace('/images/logo1.png', '');

        var logo0 = logo_prefix + '/images/logo.png';
        var logo1 = logo_prefix + '/images/logo1.png';

        var windowsize = $('.wrapper').width();

        if ((windowsize) > 600 && src !== logo0){

            logo.attr('src', logo0);

        }else if((windowsize) <= 600 && src !== logo1){

            logo.attr('src', logo1);
        }
    });

    $(window).trigger('resize');

});
```

The solution to my first problem (script not working at all) is realizing that JQuery in Wordpress works in a no-conflict mode. 
[more info](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)

The solution to my last problem (CSS and JQuery calculate width of a document differently) is found [here](http://www.fourfront.us/blog/jquery-window-width-and-media-queries).

Solutions for most other problems provided by @Artur Filipiak. Thank you :)